# Connection from MySQL to remote DB - possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc, odbc

is it possible to create a connection from a MySQL DB to a remote database (probably Oracle) using something like an ODBC/JDBC connector? I need to create a trigger on the MySQL side that performs an insert/update on a table in the remote DB.

Can MySQL act as a client in this way?

Thanks
Craig

Comment: Hi Hugh - no. It seems that this isn't possible. MySQL does not suport DB links to anything other than itself. If the far end was also MySQL then we could have used federated tables, but the only option was complex looking middleware on the Oracle side. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that you can connect to MySql from Oracle, not that I have done it myself, but I am not sure if it can be done the other way round.

If a connection from Oracle to MySql can solve your problem then have a search for 'Oracle Database Heterogeneous Connectivity'